# How to debug node.js app typescript file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an Node.js app written by typescript. I have VisualStudio 2013 and Node.js tools for Visual Studio, so I can debug compiled .js files in node.js runtime.
I can debug typescript files for browser html application.
How can I debug typescript files for node.js environment?

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to debug nodejs javascript applications using webstorm : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bKsDoFj83o I would suggest doing the same in typescript case i.e. debug your js.

Comment: My question is about how to debug typescript (not js). I want to put breakpoint into typescript code, like for code running in browser: http://i.imgur.com/2cV1LcA.png
In fact, I don't want to see javascript code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this a while ago and found it quite frustrating, I don't think it's possible to use the Visual Studio debugger for TypeScript with Node applications at the moment. You're also limited to using Internet Explorer for debugging and most developers seem to use Chrome these days.

That said Node and TypeScript debugging is possible, there's a [link here](http://holtcode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/typescript-nodejs-development-part-5.html). The process is a little funky but basarat is on the right track - WebStorm is probably a superior development environment for JavaScript applications and it has good support for the compile to languages (TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Dart). I haven't tried debugging TypeScript with Node apps using WebStorm but according to [this thread](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/512) it is possible.

UPDATE:

I've just had a quick look at the NTVS site ([see here](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/291)) and there are workarounds but they're not easy and this remains a work in progress

Answer (score 0):

With the 1.0 beta release of NTVS it is now very simple to debug node.js applications in visual studio (version 2013), as this release contains the typescript compile templates which previous versions did not contain. The new functionality lets you debug directly in your typescript code.

If you are using previous versions you can get around the missing templates by having two projects in your solution, one for a web application (this does the typescript build) and one for the nodejs tools to debug the js code.